# Weird DNS behavior

Tags: networking, server, dns

I got hold of a really [cute little PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucNFw.jpg), that I want to fiddle around with as a little side-project. It has a normal LAN connection via Ethernet  and the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration is

```
# loopback: lo
auto  lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   192.168.1.11
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  netmask   255.255.255.0
  gateway   192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Now, everything runs smoothly, the PC binds to `192.168.1.11` and I can ssh into it. However, `curl google.com` fails (directly connecting using the IP `173.194.112.255` works). So, something's gotta be wrong with the nameservers.

And here comes the strange part: After `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` all DNS queries work. And this happens after every reboot. I have to manually restart `eth0`, before I can resolve domain names.

Currently I cope with that by having an Upstart script restart the interface 10 seconds after booting. But I'd really like to fix the cause and not the symptom.

Is it my fault or is there some bug? I'm currently running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS for compatibility reasons.

---

After a fresh restart (without restarting the interface)

`/etc/resolv.conf` is empty (only comments).
`/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/{head,base}` are empty (only comments).

After restarting the interface

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

`/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/{head,base}` are empty (only comments).

Comment: What is in /etc/resolv.conf?  Also, if you have /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head and /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base, what's in there?

Comment: Very strange - I'd guess you're right about DNS causing the problem. What's the output of `nslookup google.com`?

Comment: Before if restart: timeout (as expected). After if restart: multiple IP addresses (as expected).